# What encryption technology does UiPath use?

Tags: encryption, securestring, uipath

What encryption technology does UiPath use?

For both normal transactions and for SecureString to store credentials?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming. The best source of information for this is contacting the company.

Comment: Just as a fact. You can write a secure string anywhere. So if you write it in an txt file you would be able to see the password.

Answer (score 0):

UiPath uses the AES_CBC_256 encryption algorithm.

https://www.uipath.com/kb-articles/uipath-is-hipaa-and-fips-compliant